# Customizing Salesforce1 Community Mobile app icon

Tags: community, salesforce1-app, mobile

I'm deploying a Customer Community with Web and Mobile app.
How can I set the mobile's app icon (the icon which appears on the phone's homepage), to be my own companies icon?

Comment: I believe you need to create a bespoke application using the Salesforce Mobile SDK if you want to have custom UI, including the app icon etc. As far as I'm aware you cannot achieve this with SF1.